# Does XSLFO support fixed layout?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I am using xslfo to generate PDF from my XML file, but whenever I edit something in my source documents, it will impact on pagination of output, that cause some indexing issue that runs according to there appearance.

Are there any attributes or elements to handle or to fix this behaviour?

Comment: You present no code or issue that anyone can diagnose. Consider redoing your  question with concrete example or what you desire, what you tried and why it is not working.

Comment: If you build your index the right way (i.e. using page number references, not manually-entered text), changes in pagination will be automatically reflected in the index.

Comment: Yes, @Hobbes you are right, but in this case we are converting legal data, that reference in other book also, some time there is editorial input in source that will impact on pages, and we have instruction that all pages start and end data remain on same location.

Comment: Does your source document contain page breaks? Or is it one continuous flow?

Comment: Yes it contains page break information as processing instruction.

Comment: If you have the page breaks in the source document, you could try and use `keep-together.within-page="always"` to keep everything in the same page, and transform page breaks in empty blocks with `break-after="page"` so that they are the only feasible positions for a break.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have the following situation:

1. Initially, a page is almost filled with text.
2. The text is edited and becomes longer. Now it doesn't fit on one page any more.

You want to know if there's a way to automatically change the formatting so the text will fit on one page again.

Unfortunately you can't do this with XSL-FO alone. As far as I know, there is no way to specify "this block of text has to fit on one page, and if it doesn't fit, make the font size smaller until it fits".

You'd have to do some post-processing, along the line of 'count the pages in the PDF, if the page count is larger than X, change a variable in the FO template to make the text smaller and render again'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. currently we handle this issue with adjusting line-height and line-spacing, but this need manual editing in FO, Thanks for your input but i need some automatic solution.